# Evaluate string

Tags: php, string, boolean

I have (true) or (false) assigned in string variable like:

`$chk="(true) or (false)";`

Now I'd like to evaluate the string if the string will evaluate true or false as in above it should return false?

For instance:

`$chk1="(true) and (false)";`

will return false.

The above method is implied in a web app feature where a user has to be promoted to next level by checking if he has cleared other levels. The ways to clear level has combination of logical facts like above.

Comment: Lazy way: `eval`. Not-so-lazy way: learn about grammars and parsers and write your own.

Comment: You may want to consider other ways of storing that kind of data, e.g JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try exhaustive method. It's simplest.

```
$chk = "(false) or (false)";
preg_match('/\((true|false)\)\s(or|and)\s\((true|false)\)/i', $chk, $res);
if (empty($res)) die('Error string!');
if (strtolower($res[1]) == 'true')  $a = TRUE;
if (strtolower($res[1]) == 'false') $a = FALSE;
if (strtolower($res[3]) == 'true')  $b = TRUE;
if (strtolower($res[3]) == 'false') $b = FALSE;
if (strtolower($res[2]) == 'or')  var_dump($a or $b);
if (strtolower($res[2]) == 'and') var_dump($a and $b);
```

Improved some.

Comment: Can you at least add salient details on that?

Comment: @chridam The above method is implied in a web app feature where a user has to be promoted to next level by checking if he has cleared other levels. The ways to clear level has combination of logical facts like above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it would be quite useful for other users as well if you could expand this in your answer.

Comment: @Wilon what is exhaustive method any clue? sorry for asking once more